# Selinium Install trouble

Tags: python, selenium

I'm struggling to install selenium correctly, I tried to run the test script provided by the Selenium documentation. I have python 3 and python 2 installed, is it possible to force pip to install to python 2.7 and not 3? Maybe that is my issue? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Test Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

1: First I installed selenium with pip

```
sudo pip install selenium
```

2: I tried to run the test script

```
python TestSelenium.py
```

Traceback Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSelenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

3: Now if I try with python3 it finds it installed in /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium

```
python3 TestSelenium.py
```

TraceBack Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestSelenium.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f9f9f184c18>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using selenium Firefox webdriver, you have to download geckodriver. You can download it from "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases".

Then specify the geckodriver path as given below:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= your_geckogriver_path)
```

I think this will work. Please try it.

Comment: Face palm! Yea that did the trick I thought I looked over the error message carefully but must have missed "gekodriver" Thank you for your help.